# SQL Server nest JSON output

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nested-json

This is my SQL Server table:

[image: sql table]

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE countries
(
    continent nvarchar(10),
    country nvarchar(10),
    city nvarchar(10),
);
```

And I have this data like this:

```
INSERT INTO countries
VALUES ('asia', 'inda', 'new delhi'),
       ('asia', 'inda', 'hyderabad'),
       ('asia', 'inda', 'mumbai'),
       ('asia', 'korea', 'seoul'),
       ('asia', 'inda', 'milan'),
       ('europe', 'italy', 'rome'),
       ('europe', 'italy', 'milan');
```

I need JSON output in this format:

```
Asia 
{
  india
  {
      city: new delhi
      city: Hyderabad
      city: Mumbai
  }
  Korea 
  {
      city: seoul
      city: busan
  }
}
Europe
{
  Italy
  {
      city: rome
      city:milan
      city:naples
  } 
}
```

I tried so many queries, but I am not getting it:

```
select continent, country, city 
from countries 
group by continent, country 
for json auto
```

which doesn't return the desired output.

Comment: Not without Dynamic SQL or at least some string manipulation.    Posting images of sample data is not very useful.  Please post sample data as formatted text

Comment: is this a python question ?  if so, what have you tried ?

Comment: You also may want to post some valid JSON as the desired results

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the output you wanted was actually real JSON (and not the pseudo-JSON you posted), it is possible if difficult to get dynamic keys.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG` nor `JSON_OBJ_AGG` which would have made this much easier. Instead we need to hack `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`

```sql
WITH cities AS (
    SELECT
      c.continent,
      c.country,
      json = '[' + STRING_AGG(j.json, ',') + ']'
    FROM countries c
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          c.city
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) j(json)
    GROUP BY
      c.continent,
      c.country
),
countries AS (
    SELECT
      c.continent,
      json = '{' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(c.country, 'json') + '":' + c.json, ',') + '}'
    FROM cities c
    GROUP BY
      c.continent
)
SELECT
  '{' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(c.continent, 'json') + '":' + c.json, ',') + '}'
FROM countries c;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd299a654f18fbb1d3a22d854577ca99)

**Result:**

```json
{
  "asia": {
    "inda": [
      {
        "city": "new delhi"
      },
      {
        "city": "hyderabad"
      },
      {
        "city": "mumbai"
      },
      {
        "city": "milan"
      }
    ],
    "korea": [
      {
        "city": "seoul"
      }
    ]
  },
  "europe": {
    "italy": [
      {
        "city": "rome"
      },
      {
        "city": "milan"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```